# How reset the values in html

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, ngmodel, close-button

when the user made an unnecessary changes and dont want to save it then it should reset the values to previous values when the user clicks on cancel button.Any solutions

```
<div class="org-event" *ngIf="org.eventsettings">
    <div class="event-title">Title</div>
    <br/>
    <label><input type="number" [(ngModel)]="expires" pattern="^[0-9]{1,3}$"/> An Event Begins at {seconds}</label>
    <label *ngIf = "condition1" ><input type="number" [(ngModel)]="org.value"/> value</label>
    <label *ngIf = "condition2" ><input type="number" min="1" max="3" pattern="[1-3]" [(ngModel)]="org.members"/> Quantity</label>

    <br/>
    <button class="even-success" (click)="save(org._id);"> Save </button>
    <button class="even-success" (click)= "org.eventsettings=''"> Cancel </button>
</div>
```

Comment: where do the previous values come from?  do you just want to clear the input fields?  can you use javascript?

Comment: not sure if it will work with angular (haven't touched it for quite a while) but have you tried adding a <button type="reset">reset</button> or otherwise create a button and on click clear your model values via js.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze <buttin type = "reset">reset </button>, this works fine but only with first label in my code. rest 2 labels value and members are not. so i tried this `<button type="reset" (click)= "org.eventsettings='';org.value=30;org.members=2;">reset</button>` but it resets wrongly i just want to discard the changes of one particular label but it resets everything. any here please

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the cancel button, call this function:

```js
function clearValues() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  while (i < inputs.length) {
    inputs[i].value = "";
    i++;
  }
}
```

All in all, it gets all of the inputs on the page and sets their values to a blank string.